# Julia cannot reproduce the rand

Tags: random, julia

I am just reading and practicing the "3.5.2.1 rand" section of https://juliadatascience.io/standardlibrary and found the code below cannot reproduce same random numbers:

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.7.0 (2021-11-30)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using Random: rand, randn, seed!

julia> my_seed = seed!(123)
Random.TaskLocalRNG()

julia> rand(my_seed, 3)

3-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.521213795535383
 0.5868067574533484
 0.8908786980927811

julia> rand(my_seed, 3)
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.19090669902576285
 0.5256623915420473
 0.3905882754313441
```

The snapshot of the book:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well spotted. Running `rand(my_seed, 3)` twice shouldn't give the same output. This problem was caused by a bug in Books.jl. The Books package stores outputs in files as a sort of caching mechanism. Unfortunately, two identical blocks of code will be written to the same file path, so the output for the last block overrides the output for the first block. I still haven't found a nice solution to that problem and normally it isn't a problem because the same code will usually give the same output, but not for calling `rand`.

This problem will be fixed in the HTML and PDF version on the website about 30 minutes after https://github.com/JuliaDataScience/JuliaDataScience/pull/235 is merged.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the second call to `seed!` that's in the book.

Comment: The screenshot is right after the section that calls `seed!(123)` twice, and it explicitly suggests passing `my_seed` as an argument so that one wouldn't need to repeatedly call `seed!`. It's strange, I've never tried it like that, and I certainly can't reproduce what the section suggests.

Comment: I think their explanation is wrong. `seed!(123)` doesn't return a seed, it applies seed 123 to the global random number generator, and returns this. You can ignore what it returns since this implicit anyway: `rng = Random.seed!(123); rand(rng, 1:99)` is the same as `Random.seed!(123); rand(1:99)`.

Comment: Yeah definitely a problem in the book. The values it shows in the screenshot are values 4-6 returned from the RNG with that seed. If it was correct, it would be values 1-3.

Comment: @mcabbott Hi, what's the role of passing the `my_seed` as the first argument in `rand()`?

Comment: It makes `rand` use the same `rng` instance. Part of the problem with the example in the book is that `my_seed=seed!(123)` doesn't construct a seed, but an `rng` instance.

Comment: `rand(rng, ...)` implicitly mutates the `rng`. That's how calling `rand` doesn't always give you the same number. `rand(...)` without passing in an explicit `rng` instance does the same thing, except it mutates a "global" (per task in 1.7+) `rng` instance